# How to use SUM and MAX on the same column?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, sql-order-by, sql-limit

So I'm having an SQL table where I will need find out the product that has been purchased the most meaning that I need to do a SUM and a group by on all the quantity of the products:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM PURCHASE GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
```

However when I try to find the product with the maximum amount of purchases it gives me an error:

```
SELECT MAX(QUANTITY) FROM(SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM PURCHASE GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to name the SUM() column.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What if there are ties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just order by and keep the top record only:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) SUM_QUANTITY
FROM PURCHASE 
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID 
ORDER BY SUM_QUANTITY DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The actual syntax might vary accross RDBMS. The above would work in MySQL and Postgres.

In SQL Server, you would use `SELECT TOP (1) ... ORDER BY SUM_QUANTITY DESC`.

In Oracle >= 12c, you would use `SELECT ... ORDER BY SUM_QUANTITY DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`.

You also have to consider the possibilty of ties in the first position, for which there are different strategies depending on your requirement and RDBMS.